# Pascal comparing strings

Tags: string, pascal

I need to see if one string is not the same AS EMPTY STRING. Something like:
string != '';
How can I achieve it in Pascal?

Answer (score 4):

The inequality operator is '<>', `string <> '';`.

Comment: Yeah, You are right I had other problem in code and it could not work but I have fixed it and now it works without problems. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Length** function, which will return the string length.

```
s:='My string';
x:=Length(s);
if( x > 1 ) then writeln('The string is not empty') 
            else writeln('The string is empty');
```

Comment: The question was how to check if a string is empty. You don't need a function that returns the length of the string; a simple `str <> ''` will suffice, and is much faster. (It's also less typing, and there is no `strlength` in Pascal; there are `Length` and `strlen`, but no `strlength`.)

Comment: @KenWhite Actually a mere `str <> ''` will not suffice, since [`''` will be expanded](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Special:PermaLink/4013241#Equality) to the length of `str` using space characters. Unless you _want_ to check for an empty or possibly _all-space_ `string`, the `length` method is “the” correct method. You could also use `EQ`/`NE` which implicitly uses `length`.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt: Um... Pascal does not have EQ/NE, and comparing a string variable to an empty string using `<>` works perfectly fine. Did you misread the tags for this post? Maybe you should look again.

Comment: @KenWhite This is defined in ISO/IEC standard 10206:1990 (E) “Extended Pascal.” In ISO/IEC standard 7185:1990 (E) “Pascal” it is not possible to compare string types of _different_ lengths, so I presume the OP is referring to EP.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt: But if you look at the OP's comment to Sertac's answer above, they said that `<>` worked perfectly fine, so apparently even a decade ago the OP was using something newer than a compiler that complied with a 20-year (now 30+ year) old standard.